# Collectstatic command is not available in Django 1.4

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

So I'm trying to run collectstatic to push some files to AWS, but I keep getting a "unknown command" error. When running manage.py help I get a list of subcommands, and sure enough collectstatic is not there. I have looked also in the installed apps part of settings.py and the staticfiles app is installed. Python is version 2.7 and Django is 1.4

This project was not built by me. I'm just a frontend developer who has been dragged into the world of programming D: Maybe the solution is really easy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check settings.py for `django.contrib.staticfiles` in `INSTALLED_APPS` and `django.core.context_processors.static` in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`

Answer (score 4):

For those for whom the accepted answer did not work, doing

`python manage.py collectstatic`
**worked** while

`python django-admin.py collecstatic` *did not*.

Maybe that can help some.

Comment: Worked for me. Any idea why this occurs?

Comment: This is still a mystery for me. The latest documentation (for Django 1.5.2 as of now) still mentions the command that does not work. Maybe I have a third-party app that is overriding the settings.

Comment: I'm on 1.5.2 on webfaction and the only third party apps I have installed are south and django-autocomplete-lite. Yet django-admin.py collectstatic  doesn't work (and isn't listed under help). That might help narrow things down.

Comment: Wow, this is weird. I tried your suggestion and it has worked. The weird part is, my previous trial was also the same command from this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/28440755/2483127 . or is there a difference that I cannot see?