# Django Markdown Editor does not show up

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-apps

I'm creating my very first Django application (I'm also a novice at Python, so the problem could be anywhere.)

I'm following this tutorial step by step, to get the HTML editor at 5:53 ([here](http://youtu.be/7rgph8en0Jc?t=5m53s)), however I still get the default TextField at http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/blog/entry/add/

Any help on diagnosing the problem would be appreciated.
Thanks!

### My Files :

**projects/qblog/blog/admin.py :**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . import models
from django_markdown.admin import MarkdownModelAdmin

class EntryAdmin(MarkdownModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("title" , "created")
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug" : ("title", )}

admin.site.register(models.Entry, EntryAdmin)
```

**projects/qblog/qblog/urls.py :**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^markdown/', include("django_markdown.urls")),
)
```

**projects/qblog/blog/models.py :**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class EntryQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def published(self):
        return self.filter(publish=True)

class Entry(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,unique = True)
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    objects = EntryQuerySet.as_manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Blog Entry"
        verbose_name_plural = "Blog Entries"
        ordering = ["-created"]
```

**projects/qblog/qblog/settings.py :**

```
"""
Django settings for qblog project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.dev20150210173028.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'secretkey'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'blog',
    'django_markdown',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'qblog.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'qblog.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 6):

In the video's comments you can get the answer. Modify the next files:

**models.py**

```
from django_markdown.models import MarkdownField
...
body = MarkdownField()
```

**settings.py**

```
...
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

# Markdown
MARKDOWN_EDITOR_SKIN = 'simple'
```

**urls.py**

```
...
from yourapp import settings
if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**In shell run:**

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Comment: Thank you. +1. I moved to another computer but I will try this and let you know ASAP.

Comment: I think there is a typo at the last line. And I couldn't get it work. collectstatic runs, I restart the server, nothing changed.

Comment: Serve the static files in development adding the urls.py's code at the bottom of yours (change yourapp for yours)

Comment: For me collecting the static files was the only thing needed to solve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem. However, when I add Mr. iago1460's code without the `urls.py` part,after I run:

```
python manage.py collectstatic,
```

the `django_markdown` can work ,I use python 2.7 and django 1.8 version

the urls.py code here

```
from django.conf.urls import  include, url
from django.contrib import admin
#import settings

#if settings.DEBUG:
    #from django.conf.urls.static import static
    #urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

urlpatterns = [
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'cblog.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^markdown/', include("django_markdown.urls")),
    url(r'^',include('blog.urls')),
```

]

here is my project files ,my project name is cblog ,app is blog:

djtest/cblog/cblog:

```
__init__.py  __init__.pyc  settings.py  settings.pyc  urls.py  urls.pyc  wsgi.py  wsgi.pyc
```

djtest/cblog:

```
 blog  cblog  db.sqlite3  manage.py  static
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah i found this problem too when i was trying qblog tutorial. i'm using Python 3.4 and Django 1.8.1, But on the step to install markdown package, i decide to change the package into Django CKEditor.

Visit https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-ckeditor to install.

After CKEditor has been installed properly, if you find the problem in import forms.util flattat when you are running the server.
Change your widgets.py under ckeditor folder (on windows environment the directory is under C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\ckeditor), then change the line :

**from django.forms.util import flatatt**

to

**from django.forms.utils import flatatt**

Follow in how to use CKEditor then implement it on your qblog.
The result will be like this :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this easier way:

in **admin.py** :

```
from django_markdown.admin import MarkdownModelAdmin
from django_markdown.widgets import AdminMarkdownWidget
from django.db.models import TextField


class EntryAdmin(MarkdownModelAdmin):
    ... #your_code
    formfield_overrides = {TextField: {'widget': AdminMarkdownWidget}}

admin.site.register(models.Entry, EntryAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you are using python 2x
Now,what happens is that the stylesheets and javascript are not loaded

So what you can do is:

```
from django_markdown.widgets import AdminMarkdownWidget
  from django.db.models import TextField

  class EntryAdmin(MarkdownModelAdmin):
      list_display = ("title", "created")
      prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}
      # Next line is a workaround for Python 2.x
      formfield_overrides = {TextField: {'widget': AdminMarkdownWidget}}
```

and this will work!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Python 2.x You need add that:**

formfield_overrides = {TextField: {'widget': AdminMarkdownWidget}}